# Nginx error with django staticfiles "no such file or directory"

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to make nginx process a request for static files in a django application, but it throws an error

```
 [error] 20#20: *1 open() "/home/app/web/staticfiles/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css" failed (2: No 
 such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET 
 /staticfiles/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:1337", referrer: 
 "http://127.0.0.1:1337/admin/"
```

What did i do wrong? I understand that the request comes to the right place, but for some reason it is not possible to make a response from this directory

nginx.conf

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

     location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn pets.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
COPY . .
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $POSTGRES_HOST $POSTGRES_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

cd pets

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Does the file `/home/app/web/staticfiles/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css` exist?

Comment: @JohnGordon it should be automatically create by django, the problem with the folders

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure this is the issue, but remove the trailing slash in your nginx config.  Instead of:

```
location /staticfiles/ {
    alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
}
```

use this

```
location /staticfiles/ {
   alias /home/app/web/staticfiles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help

Comment: Oh are you running `manage.py collectstatic` if you aren't the files aren't moved into the directory

Comment: Yes, it was the main problem)) Thank you, you can edit your answer and i will accept it

Comment: Oh, i still have the same error despite the fact that the file exists, I got into the contents of the container and made sure of this...